# How to access subclass variable from superclass?

Tags: java, class, variables, subclass, superclass

Say I have 2 classes, A and B. B is a subclass of A, and B has a variable specific to that class, example:

```
private class A{}
private class B extends A{int x = 5;}
```

And I store a B as an A,

```
A instB = new B();
```

How do I access x in B? In this example it's a constant, but in my program it isn't, so i need some way to access the variable itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to store the object as 'A' instead of 'B', then I believe your only answer would be to cast 'instB' to back to 'B' for you to access that member.

```
int member = ((B)instB).x;
```

But something about that software design just doesn't seem right if you need to access child class members from the superclass.

Comment: This worked! Thanks! And the reason I'm storing it like this is because its an array of the superclass with various subclasses. This is for a game.

Comment: I am glad it worked, good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

If you determine that your class instB is of type A, InstB is not going to have access of all variables or methods of class B. You will have to put the variable in class A or initialize your Object as type B.